# My own method used in list_display and value as boolean icon

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I wrote my own method used in list_display (admin class), like this:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('my_own_method')

    def my_own_method(self, obj):
        if [condition]:       
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```

but this value is displayed on list as text (True or False), not as default django boolean icons like this:
[image]

What should I do to change this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('my_own_method')

    def my_own_method(self, obj):
        if [condition]:       
            return True
        else: 
            return False
    my_own_method.boolean = True
```

which can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) on `list_display`:

> If the string given is a method of the model, ModelAdmin or a callable that returns True or False Django will display a pretty "on" or "off" icon if you give the method a boolean attribute whose value is True.